# How to change structure fields using ctypes python pointers

Tags: python, ctypes

Below is the code where I'm accessing the values of dll using ctypes.

My intention is to store the structure fields addresses. Whenever the values in the structure changes ,I can access the addresses and get changed values.

```
DUMMY_DLL_PATH = "dummyModel.dll"

class MyStruct(ctypes.Structure):  
    _fields_ = [("field_one", ctypes.c_int),  
                ("field_two", ctypes.c_int)]  

d_m = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(DUMMY_DLL_PATH)  

d_i = MyStruct.in_dll(d_m,"dummy_In")  

in_field = ctypes.c_int(d_i.field_one)  

#storing the address  
b = ctypes.addressof(in_field)  
b_v = ctypes.cast(b,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))  

k= b_v.contents   

print 'before',d_i.field_one,k.value  
#changing the value  
d_i.field_one = 10  

print 'After',d_i.field_one,k.value
```

#### Output:

```
Before 0 0  
After 10 0
```

Through pointers, the values are not getting changed.remains 0

Answer (score 4):

The problem is `in_field` is a new `c_int` object occupying different memory than the original structure.  What you want is `c_int.from_buffer` ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html?highlight=from_buffer#ctypes._CData.from_buffer)) which shares the memory of the original object.  Here's an example:

#### Windows DLL source `x.c` compiled with `cl /LD x.c`:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int one;
    int two;
};

__declspec(dllexport) struct MyStruct myStruct = {1,2};
```

#### Python script:

```
from ctypes import *

class MyStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("one", c_int),
        ("two", c_int)]
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'MyStruct({},{})'.format(self.one,self.two)

dll = CDLL('x')
struct = MyStruct.in_dll(dll,"myStruct")
alias1 = c_int.from_buffer(struct, MyStruct.one.offset)
alias2 = c_int.from_buffer(struct, MyStruct.two.offset)
print struct
print 'before',alias1,alias2
struct.one = 10
struct.two = 20
print 'after',alias1,alias2
```

#### Output:

```
MyStruct(1,2)
before c_long(1) c_long(2)
after c_long(10) c_long(20)
```